# Accessing a external browser with c#

Tags: c#, search, browser, external, element

i was just wondering if you can access an browser externally with c#, and see if there is a certain word is in the webpage?

I have done a lot of research, but none that are specific to what my problem is, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported (unless you hack something or write a browser extension and communicate it).

However, you can always download the web page content as a string and use C# string search methods. for example:

```
string url = 'http://...';
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string content = client.DownloadString(url);

// And now you can search
if (content.Contains("Zyak"))
{
    ...
}
```